# How to export an output of Table1() R function without losing any variable

Tags: r, export

I have the data below, and I want to export the out put of the `table1()` function into an excel file, but the file.xlsx that I got is not similar to the output, the group1 variable is not displayed in the excel file.

```
library(table1)
library(xlsx)
data<-data.frame(group1=c("AA","BB","AA","AA","AA","BB","BB"),
                 group2=c("A","A","C","A","B","B","C"),
                 x=c(0,1,1,0,1,0,1))

t<-table1(~ factor(x)| group1+group2, data=data, 
            topclass="Rtable1-zebra" )

write.xlsx(t,file = "file_path/file.xlsx",row.names=FALSE)
```

here is the output of table1 r function:

[image]

and here is the excel file output:

[image]

Is there any solution to export the output without losing any variable ?

Comment: Are you saying that the excel file isn't showing the "A","B", and "Overall"?

Comment: @neuron sorry, I corrected the output, I'm saying that in the excel file doesn't contain the line of  AA, BB, and overall